# Upload a file to an SFTP server using PDFBox save method without storing the file to the local system?

Tags: java, sftp, pdfbox, jsch

I'm trying to save the edited PDF which I fetched from the remote server back to its location without having it downloaded/stored on the local machine. I'm using JSch SFTP method to get the input PDF file from the SFTP server using

```
x = new BufferedInputStream(channelSftp.get("example.pdf"));
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(x);
```

and after doing some edits using PDFbox, I'm trying to save it using:

```
documents.save(new File("ftp/path/location"));
```

I am not able to because I know it only works for your local directory only. Also I can see that `document.save` accept OutputStream` parameter, but I do not know how to use it here.

I don't have any problems with taking input using stream reader.
All I need is to save that edited PDF back to its location (possibly replace) without having to download it on my local system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ChannelSftp.put` overload that returns `OutputStream`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.lang.String-):

```
try (OutputStream out = channelSftp.put("example.pdf")) {
    documents.save(out);
}
```